# If I have this relation: $f(x)f(1-y) = f(y)f(1-x)$ and I know that $f'()<0$, what can I say of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: calculus

I understand that, for instance, $x=y$ satisfies the equation, but how can I be sure that this is the only solution?

Comment: Taking the total derivative of both sides $[f^\prime(x)f(1-y)+f(y)f^\prime(1-x)]dx=[f^\prime(y)f(1-x)+f(x)f^\prime(1-y)]dy$ and simplifying, $y=1-x$ are also solutions.

Comment: @Lucozade, if I understand correctly, this is not a functional equation, but equation in $x$ and $y$, so taking derivatives is unjustifiable. Let's say I want to solve $x - 3 = 0$, take derivative and get $1 = 0$. Do I conclude that there were no solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, since it might not be true. It depends on $f$. For example, let $f(x) = 1- e^x$. Then, $x = \ln(1+e), y = 2$ is a solution to your equation. (Thanks to smcc who pointed exact solution to me).

Comment: @TSant, thank you. Just to make sure: don't feel obligated to accept my answer just because it was me who asked you to accept an answer. Personally, I think the one by Cuspy Code is better than this one, but it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the factors so that $x$ and $y$ are separated:

$$\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)} = \frac{f(1-y)}{f(y)}$$

For an $f$ that has this quotient constant, e.g. $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}-x$, the equality is satisfied for all values of $x$ and $y$. If the quotient is not constant, then we can see from symmetry considerations that the equality is true for $x=y$, and if $f$ satisfies the condition $\forall x:f(1-x)=f(x)$, the equality is also true for $1-x=y$. But in the last case we have $-f'(1-x)=f'(x)$ which I assume is forbidden by $f'()<0$ if I interpret the question correctly.

EDIT: As Ennar's answer shows, depending on the function $f$ there can be additional $x$ and $y$ values that also satisfy the equality.