# $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=\frac{f(1−x)}{f(1-y)}$ and I know that $f′(x)<0, f(x)>0 $ $\forall x$, what can I say of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: calculus

I would like to have a general solution. I can see that $x=y$ is a solution but is it the only one?

Comment: Can you fix your title? It's unclear.

Comment: What about your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964637/if-i-have-this-relation-fxf1-y-fyf1-x-and-i-know-that-f0-wha/2964785#2964785)?

Comment: @Ennar, I added f()>0.

Comment: TSant, yes, I see that (that's why I didn't vote to close this one as a duplicate). But, it looks like you abandoned your previous question, since there was no feedback from you. It was not fault of those that answered that your data was incomplete at that time. Some acknowledgment would be nice, you know. Like accepting an answer that you find most useful by clicking on a check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Ennar, you are right. I just did it. Sorry, as you can see I am new to Stack. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the only solutions are where $x=y$.

Let $g$ be the function given by $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(1-x)}$$ for all $x$. Then $$g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)f(1-x)+f(x)f'(1-x)}{[f(1-x)]^2}<0$$
because $f'<0$ and $f>0$. So $g$ is  a strictly decreasing function and therefore the only solutions to $g(x)=g(y)$ are where $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

From
$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=\frac{f(1−x)}{f(1-y)}
$,
$f(x) > 0,
f'(x) < 0$,
we get
$\frac{f(1-y)}{f(y)}=\frac{f(1−x)}{f(x)}
$
so
$\frac{f(1−x)}{f(x)}
$
is constant,
call it $c$.

Then
$\frac{f(1−x)}{f(x)}
=c$.
Let $x = \frac12
=1-x$,
so
$c
=\frac{f(\frac12)}{f(\frac12)}
=1
$.

Therefore
$f(1-x) = f(x)$,
so that $f$
is symmetrical
around $\frac12$,
or
$f(\frac12+x)
=f(\frac12-x)$.

Therefore,
if $g$ is any even function
(i.e., $g(x) = g(-x)$),
then
$f(\frac12+x) = g(x)$
or
$f(x) = g(x-\frac12)$
is a solution.

Comment: I don't think OP meant that as a functional equation, but equation in $x$ and $y$ for some $f$ with given properties.

Answer (score 0):

The key point you should be looking at here is that $f$ is a decreasing, positive function (hence no messy division by zero issues). Then, assume that $x>y$ or $x<y$. This will immediately tell you something about the ratio $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$. Use this information to get an inequality about $(1-x)$ and $(1-y)$, and see where that leads you.